# How to find more than 1 successive shortest paths between two vertices in unweighted and undirected graph using BFS?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, breadth-first-search

I have tried to find and print more than one successive shortest paths between two vertices in the undirected graph. Using BFS as DFS will not be optimal in this case, as it can go deep into the stack.

Wrote this function but not getting the correct response and also tried to find help over StackOverflow and other platforms but did not find a solution for **undirected** graph.

Comment: Is the graph weighted?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here.  Not everyone here knows C++.  Please [edit] the question to replace the code with concise pseudocode.

Comment: @D.W. It'm not sure that the question is about finding $k$ successive shortest paths in a graph (which might have different lengths). It seems to me that the goal is to find $k$ distinct paths from $s$ to $t$, all of which are shortest. It might be worth to clarify this in the question. Clearly a solution for the first problem implies a solution for the second problem (but not vice-versa).

Comment: @Steven, hmm, if it's unclear, perhaps this should be put on hold until that is cleared up.  Is there a difference?  If there are $k$ distinct paths all tied for shortest, then using an algorithm for finding the $k$ shortest paths will find all of them.  If there aren't, that will also be apparent after running an algorithm to find the $k$ shortest paths.

Comment: There is a difference in the sense that finding the $k$ shortest paths from $s$ to $t$ is "harder" than just finding $k$ distinct paths from $s$ to $t$ that are all shortest. The simple approach in my answer works for the latter problem but not for the former.

Comment: @kamal: As DW said, you should replace your code with a corresponding pseudocode and possibly a high-level description of your approach... but, out of curiosity, which language is that?

Comment: @Steven It is go language, I have updated the question with successive paths.

Comment: @DW en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing  is for a directed graph with weight. I am asking for unweighted and undirected graph.

Comment: Those algorithms can also be applied to unweighted undirected graphs (set all weights=1, treat each undirected as a directed edge in both directions).